# Trying to read array into new array

Tags: c++, arrays, string, file

So I have to write a program that reads each line from a file into a string and then change that string into other strings.

Here's what the file looks like:

```
Saw 10  33.82
Drill   8   27.58
Hammer  23  76.34
Nail    13  9.54
Screwdriver 54  10.34
Boxcutter   23.11
```

And here is my ReadData function:

```
void ReadData (Hardware * &pArray, MyString filename)
{
int count = 0;
string itemLine[MAX_LINE];
int size = 0;
ifstream inFile;

inFile.open(filename);

/*inFile >> size;
if (size > MAX_LINE)*/
    size = MAX_LINE;

pArray = new Hardware[size];


for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
        getline(inFile, itemLine[i]);
}

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    int position = 0;
    int next = 0;
    pArray[i].name[count] = itemLine[i]
}



}
```

My MAX_LINE is set to 12 and I'm not sure how to stop the file from reading the blank spaces, since there's only 6 lines in the file. Other than that I can actually read the file, but afterwards I have to put the word "Saw" into it's own array and the '10' and the '33.82'. I think I'll have to use next as well which I'm not sure how to do. I'm guessing I have to use a structure which I made.

```
struct Hardware
{
char name[MAX_STRING];
int quantity;
float price;
};
```

And after all this in another function I'm going to have to multiply the 10 by the 33.82 and so on to get total prices, so they can't be strings. I think I have to use atoi for that, but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: Do yourself a favor and don't use raw arrays. We already have `std::vector` that does the necessary memory management for you. Is there any good reason you don't want to use  `std::vector`? Also `std:::string` might be a better choice for `name`.

Comment: What's your question?  You have some good ideas; do they work when you try them? You might look up `fscanf()` in C or `istream::operator>>` in C++.

Comment: I've never used a vector before, I'm not entirely sure how. It's an assignment, I'm pretty sure he wants us to use arrays.

Comment: @C0UG3R Check [the reference documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/). Also quit that course immediately and lookout for a better one. They're not teaching c++.

Comment: I started writing an answer but then found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20756968/reading-multiple-lines-from-a-file-using-getline  It is very similar to the question you were asking and might help.

Comment: C0UG3R, I empathize, it seems you're lost, there's a LOT to discuss - basically we'd have to hold a teaching session here, because from start to end what I see is you need to be walked through this. On this site two things happen which fight your need. A) Answers are supposed to just that, answers to questions. Many try to help with your kind of inquiry, and end up holding class within an answer that's editing dozens of times, amounting to an ongoing discussion. B) When these comments look like chat sessions, the website actually MOVES us into a chat session.